how to install phpbolt in a debian12 / apache2 / php-fpm environment
I have a debian12 server with apache2 and php-fpm for PHP versions 8.0, 8.1, 8.2 and 8.3.
In which configuration files do I have to extend the “extension” so that these are loaded when the page is called?
I have had “phpbolt 1.0.5” sent to me, unpacked it and placed bolt.so as bolt.php8.3.so in a directory to which apache2 has access.
In the php.ini files under /etc/php/8.3/apache2 and /etc/php/8.3/fpm I entered the line extension=‘/usr/local/src/phpBolt/bolt-php8.3.so’ and restarted apache2.
I did the same for the other php versions.
Unfortunately, apache reports the following in the Error.log:

AH01071: Got error PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bolt_decrypt() in /var/www/html/pages/test/bolt.php:6Stack trace:#0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/pages/test/bolt.php on line 6

Can someone please help me, I've already spent a lot of time searching Google.
Thank you very much
Klaus

Usually the easiest thing to do is to create a single web page and place <?php phpinfo(); on it, then visit that page in your browser and look for "Loaded Configuration File". Often the CLI and web can have different INI files, so if you need this on the CLI, too, you should repeat this.

Hi Chris,
Many thanks for the tip.
I have done it and found that I have edited the correct files.
Unfortunately it had no positive success.
I still get the message “PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bolt_decrypt()”.
Thanks anyway.
Regards
Klaus

Is there also a PHP process you can restart?

Hi Chris,
Many thanks for the tip.
Of course, there is the “php8.3-fpm” service. After I started it, everything works as it should. I should have known that.
Many thanks again.
I'm going to go stand in a corner and feel ashamed... ;-)
Best regards
Klaus

No worries, glad you found it. Sometimes it isn't obvious how all things are connected.
